# How can I retrieve the latest subscription for each user?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, inner-join

For example we have 2 tables:

```
TABLE users WITH FIELDS
    id

TABLE providers WITH FIELDS
    id

TABLE subscriptions WITH FIELDS
    id
    start_date
    provider_id - OneToMany
    user_id - OneToMany
```

And the following sql statement:

```sql
SELECT subscription.id
FROM subscriptions
INNER JOIN providers ON 
    subscriptions.provider_id = providers.id AND
    providers.id = 2
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(start_date) AS start_date
    FROM subscriptions GROUP BY user_id
) AS max USING (user_id, start_date)
```

In result, I want to get for each user the **subscription** whose **provider** is (in this case) 2 that has the latest **start_date**.
In this case, we use `provider_id` 2 but that value is dynamic.

I expected the MAX in the second INNER JOIN to take only the subscriptions whose retailer is 2, but it doesn't, it takes all the subscriptions. Why's that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is ON clause on second join? which field should be used to connect two data source?

Comment: Your schema may have a design problem.

Comment: @heximal I use USING instead of ON

Comment: It's not enough to store the start date in a record, you also need to store the end date otherwise you'll end up calculating the end date on every single query, whether you realize it or not. In this case your problem is caused because you have no easy way to calculate if a subscription is still valid "now" - because you need that end date. Trying to find the latest start date is a surrogate for that missing end date.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is like a simpler version of my actual database schema and yesterday I started to use the INNER JOIN along MAX and USING to find a solution, i'm still new to these scenarios.

Comment: If anything, the performance of what you want will be very bad even if `start_date` is indexed, because you have to perform a MAX on every query. With `start` and `end` though, and an index covering both, the condition `WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP between start_date and end_date` would be *very* fast

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In my actual database schema, on my table I have both start_date and expire_date, expire_date is always the same date as start_date but 1 year ahead, so imo it doesn't matter which one I use in this sql statement.

Comment: Never mind finding the active subscription at a point in time. Or finding the validity period of a subscription. Queries like these are called temporal queries, and while other databases support temporal tables, PostgreSQL doesn't (even though it implemented one of the first drafts 20 years ago, go figure). In temporal tables the start/end date of an interval are stored explicitly

Comment: @CristianGira `it doesn't matter which one I use in this sql statement.` if it didn't you wouldn't have to ask for help writing such a convoluted query. You could write `WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN start_date and expiry_date`. An expiry date isn't an end date anyway - someone could cancel a subscription early.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think that we got different ideas of what's happening, sorry if didn't explain my situation good enough. I don't need the active subscription, I don't care if it's expired or active, I just want the one that starts latest for each producer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240304/discussion-between-cristian-gira-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *I expected the MAX in the second INNER JOIN to take only the subscriptions whose retailer is 2, but it doesn't, it takes all the subscriptions. Why's that?*

This subquery with MAX is self-contained. If you execute it as a standalone query:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(start_date) AS start_date
    FROM subscriptions GROUP BY user_id
```

then you would expect it to return each `user_id` with its `max(start_date)`, independently of the `provider_id` field, as it is never mentioned in that query.

When it's run as a subquery inside your larger query, well, it returns exactly the same results.

You may just add the condition `WHERE provider_id=2` to that subquery.

Comment: Oh, so that's why, thank you. But one more thing, is it bad doing it this way? And if yes, is there a better approach?